# How can I delete rows that don't meet conditions of user input?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to record a macro that will delete any row in a data table that DOES NOT match a cell value in Column G that a user defines and shifts the remaining rows up. For example, if I want to delete any rows that don't have "Dec 2018" in Column G.

My understanding is that this code from Excel Campus below could generate a pop up box for a user to define what they're looking for, but I am unclear on how to change the conditions so that it deletes any row that doesn't match the condition rather than matching the condition:

```
Sub RemoveOldReleases()
'Display Yes/No message prompt before deleting rows
'Source: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/delete-rows-cell-values/

Dim lo As ListObject
Dim lRows As Long
Dim vbAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim sCriteria As Variant

  'Set reference to the sheet and Table.
  Set lo = RAW.ListObjects(1)
  lo.Parent.Activate 'Activate sheet that Table is on.

  'Clear any existing filters
  lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

  'Ask user for input
  sCriteria = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the release month your trying to keep in the format Sep 2018" _
                                    & vbNewLine & "Leave the box empty to filter for blanks.", _
                                    Title:="Filter Criteria", _
                                    Type:=2)

  'Exit if user presses Cancel button
  If sCriteria = False Then Exit Sub

  '1. Apply Filter
  lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=sCriteria

  'Count Rows & display message
  On Error Resume Next
    lRows = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, lo.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
  On Error GoTo 0

  vbAnswer = MsgBox(lRows & " Rows will be deleted.  Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo, "Delete Rows Macro")

  If vbAnswer = vbYes Then

    'Delete Rows
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      lo.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Clear Filter
    lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

  End If

End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of my data table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhXmK.png

My workbook name: MasterSKUImport.xlsm

My worksheet name: RAW

Cell Range: A1:J100000

Column with value: G

Example of a value to search for: "Sep 2018"

Bonus points if I can generate the default value in the pop up box to always be the previous month in the format Mmm YYYY (Sep 2018).

UPDATE:

I've tried this code as suggested by @SJR and it works!:

```
Sub RemoveOldReleases()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW")

  'Ask user for input
  sCriteria = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the Release Month you're trying to keep in the format Mmm YYYY (ex. Sep 2018)", _
                                Title:="Release Month", _
                                Default:=Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmm yyyy"), _
                                    Type:=2)

  'Exit if user presses Cancel button
  If sCriteria = False Then Exit Sub

  '1. Apply Filter
  ws.Range("$A$1:$J$100000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<>*" & sCriteria & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    'Delete Rows
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      ws.Range("$A$2:$J$100000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Clear Filter
    ws.Range("$A$1:$J$100000").AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: This should do it `Criteria1:="<>" & sCriteria`. That's if you're checking the whole cell contents. Otherwise `Criteria1:="<>*" & sCriteria & "*"`

Comment: Hi @SJR, thank you for your input. I've tried this but unfortunately it ends up deleting every row including the ones with the values I'm trying to save. I have updated the code snippet in my original post above, could you please take a look and see if you might know what I'm missing?

Comment: OK dates are a bit tricky in Autofilter. Are they actual dates formatted in that way or just straight text?

Comment: @SJR Just straight text

Comment: Tbh, it's a bit of a faff and I hate Excel dates! Autofilter is generally better than looping but in this case I would go for the latter, or wait for someone is better at dates than me.

Comment: @SJR Fair enough. Dates work a lot better in OpenOffice Calc for me. What if we pretended it wasn't a date I was looking to keep but a random piece of text like "Mac"? Would that make it easier?

Comment: That should work fine - try it. But change the inputbox type to 2 which is string (1 is a number I think).

Comment: @SJR that worked, thank you! I will update my question  above with the solution :)